# How do I square a number's digits?

Tags: javascript, numbers, int, digits, perfect-square

How do I square a number's digits? e.g.:

```
square(21){};
```

should result in `41` instead of `441`

Comment: I'm confused. You want to square a number, but want to get `11` instead of `121` in this example? I don't understand.

Comment: square of 11 is not 11, but 121! What should square() return: 11 or 121?!

Comment: do you want square of individual digits?

Comment: He wants the individual digits.

Comment: So, `99` would become the *string* `'8181'`?

Comment: You really should pick a better example than `11`... like, 23 -> 49, 90 -> 810

Comment: Edited.. OP please confirm.. if its ok.. then simple put logic to separate digits and square it.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? I assume you know how to square a number.

Comment: @HomeBrainBox check the answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function sq(n){
var nos = (n + '').split('');
var res="";
for(i in nos){
  res+= parseInt(nos[i]) * parseInt(nos[i]);
}

return parseInt(res);
}

var result = sq(21);
alert(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done with simple math. No need for the overhead of string processing.

```js
var result = [];
var n = 21;
while (n > 0) {
    result.push(n%10 * n%10);
    n = Math.floor(n/10);
}

document.body.textContent = result.reverse().join("");
```

In a loop, while your number is greater than 0, it...

- gets the remainder of dividing the number by `10` using the `%` operator
- squares it and adds it to an array.
- reduces the original number by dividing it by 10, dropping truncating to the right of the decimal, and reassigning it.

Then at the end it reverses and joins the array into the result string (which you can convert to a number if you wish)

Answer (score 0):

I think he means something like the following:

```
    var output = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<num.length; i++)
    {
        output.concat(Math.pow(num[i],2).toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what the OP is looking for? The square of each digit?

```
var number = 12354987,
var temp = 0;

for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    temp = String(number).charAt(i);
    output.push(Number(temp) * Number(temp));
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into an array, return a `map` of the square of the element, and rejoin the resulting array back into a string.

```
function squareEachDigit(str) {
    return str.split('').map(function (el) {
        return (+el * +el);
    }).join('');
}

squareEachDigit('99') // 8181
squareEachDigit('52') // 254
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L5s9hkwt/)

Comment: `*` will coerce, so no need for `+el * +el`; just `el * el` will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to split the numbers into their place values, then square them, then concatenate them back together. Here's how I would do it:

```
function fn(num){
    var strArr = num.toString().split('');
    var result = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++){
     result += Math.pow(strArr[i], 2) + '';
    }

    return +result;
}
```

Use [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) to square numbers like this:

`Math.pow(11,2); // returns 121`

Comment: I believe op wants the square of individual digits.