# Simple Adding square of digits of a number

Tags: javascript, exponentiation

The result of this script is not the sum of the squares of the digits of a number,  the first function works fine,  I guess the problem is in the second

```
function nToArray(a) {
  var res=[];
  var s =a.toString();
  for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){
    res[i]=s.charAt(i);}
  return res;
}

 //var a ="hola";
 //document.write(a.length);
alert(nToArray(562));
function addSq(b){
  var c=nToArray(b);
  var z=0;
  var i;
  for (i=0;i<=c.length;i++){//here 
    z+=((parseInt(c[i]))^2);}
  return z;
}

alert(addSq(81));
```

For 81 I get 15,  I don't get it.

Comment: `^` is the bitwise XOR operator. You are looking for `Math.pow`

Comment: What do you think the `^` operator does?

Comment: @MinusFour thank you,  as you can see in starting to learn programming :S

Comment: I thought that meant power...

Comment: Please take a look at http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out

Comment: At some point in the future (ES2016?), you should be able to use `**` for exponentation. See https://github.com/rwaldron/exponentiation-operator. Actually, you can already use it in Babel.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873116/how-do-i-square-a-numbers-digits.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have an exponentiation operator, `^` is a bitwise integer XOR.

You're looking for [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

```
z += Math.pow(parseInt(c[i]), 2);
```

or of course, just use `*` to multiply:

```
var value = parseInt(c[i]);
z += value * value;
```

Comment: Now it tells me Nan... I'll check it out

Comment: In your loop, you have `i<=c.length` so, last element is `NaN`, just use `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: Great,  just teaching myself programming, this website is helping me a lot thank you!

Comment: You fixed it,  I knew there was a problem with the lenght

Comment: Consider using spilt, map and reduce - it is shorter and will save you from of by one errors.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short version - sorry about the missing formatting:

```
var a=81;
console.log(a.toString().split('').map(function(i) {return Math.pow(i, 2)}).reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b}));
```

Answer (score 1):

While ^ represents an exponent in some languages, that is not the case in JavaScript.

Change

```
z+=((parseInt(c[i]))^2);
```

to

```
var tmp = parseInt(c[i]);
z+= tmp * tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

**EDIT**

```
function addSq(num){
var numNoStr = parseInt(num, 10);
var z = 0;
while (numNoStr > 0) {
    var digit = numNoStr % 10;
    z += Math.pow(digit, 2);
    numNoStr = parseInt(numNoStr / 10 , 10);
}
return z;
}
alert(addSq(81));
```

Comment: You're not using `numNoStr`.

Comment: That's correct. Should've (but forgot) replaced all inner-used "num" with "numNoStr", just in case the input is a string, my bad

Answer (score 1):

You can do this numerically:

```
function sum_of_squares_of_digits(n) {
  var s = 0;
  while (n) {
    var digit = n % 10;
    s += digit * digit;
    n = (n - digit) / 10;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Just for fun, try using regexp:

```
function sum_of_squares_of_digits(n) {
  var s = 0;
  n.toString().replace(/\d/g, d => s += d * d);
  return s;
}
```